# Group using linq return datatable

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

i have a linq query that returns Articles ordered by the number of tags that match the current article

e.g

current article has tags - tag1, tag2, tag3

tagged article 1 - tag1,tag2,tag3
tagged article 2 - tag1,tag2

linq i have is

```
 DataTable query = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()  
                           let tags = row.Field<string>("Tags").Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                           let count = tags.Count(t => currenttags.Contains(t))
                           orderby count descending
                           select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

i want to add the group by ClassName which is the article type (literature, case study, download etc)

so would be

```
group row by {row.Field<string>("ClassDisplayName")}
```

however when i add this to the query i get red sqiggles

```
   DataTable query = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()    
                           group row by {row.Field<string>("ClassDisplayName")}
                           let tags = row.Field<string>("Tags").Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                           let count = tags.Count(t => currenttags.Contains(t))                             
                           orderby count descending                             
                           select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

This is the current one that works with just the order by

```
DataTable dt = ArticleCollection(SqlClause.ToString());

        var seperator = new[] { ",", " " };
        var current = dr["Tags"].ToString();
        var currenttags = dr.Field<string>("Tags").Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        DataTable query = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()                             
                           let tags = row.Field<string>("Tags").Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                           let count = tags.Count(t => currenttags.Contains(t))
                           orderby count descending
                          // group row by row.Field<string>("ClassDisplayName") into g
                           select row).CopyToDataTable();


        if (!DataHelper.DataSourceIsEmpty(query))
        {
            TagRepeaterOutter.DataSource = query;
            TagRepeaterOutter.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: You need to provide an example that at least is quite close to compiling. 1) 'seperator' is undefined. 2) currenttags is undefined. 3) The extension method CopyToDataTable is undefined. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints, especially the section about Sample code and data.

Comment: What errors do you get. "red squiggles" is not a very precise problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to order by count, and within each value of count, group the rows by ClassDisplayName, you can try this:

```
DataTable query = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()                             
                   let tags = row.Field<string>("Tags").Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   let count = tags.Count(t => currenttags.Contains(t))
                   let displayName = row.Field<string>("ClassDisplayName")
                   orderby count descending, displayName
                   select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: so i don't need to use "group row by row.Field<string>("ClassDisplayName") into g"? sorry new to linq

Comment: if i correctly understand what you are trying to do (order by count, then by classdisplayname), then you don't need 'group'.

Comment: what i want to do with the data is bind it to nested repeater, so all casestudies will be under caserstudies and literature under literature. thats why i was thinking of usinig "group"

Comment: i'm not very familiar with nested repeater controls.  can you use them to display a hierarchy within a single table, or do you need to bind them to a parent table and related child table?

Comment: parent and child table i think, that why i was looking at grouping using linq. does that return more than one table?

Comment: afaik, group will not return multiple data tables like this.  also, looking at [this example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306154), a relationship must exist between the tables, so it sounds like you would need to set up a dataset with a parent table, child table, and relationship between them, and then create two linq queries - one to populate the parent table and one to populate the child table.  Leaving for work now -- will not be able to respond for a while.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable query = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   where (row.Field<string>("ClassDisplayName") == dr["ClassDisplayName"].ToString())
                   let tags = row.Field<string>("Tags").Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   let count = tags.Count(t => currenttags.Contains(t))
                   orderby count descending
                   select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> types = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                      group row by row.Field<string>("ClassDisplayName") into g
                                      select g.FirstOrDefault());

        DataTable dtType = types.CopyToDataTable();
```

and then another query on the inner nested repeater

```
DataTable query = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                               where (row.Field<string>("ClassDisplayName") == dr["ClassDisplayName"].ToString())
                               let tags = row.Field<string>("Tags").Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                               let count = tags.Count(t => currenttags.Contains(t))                                  
                               orderby count descending                              
                               select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

anyone have a better solution let me know